# Intermittent code signing errors with Xcode 10

Tags: xcode

Since using Xcode 10 to build our iOS project, I keep seeing an intermittent error appear with my target's extensions.

The first extension is a Today Extension (widget). Every other time I build the project, I see this error:

> Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent
>   app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the
>   parent app's
>
> Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    Not Code Signed
>
> Parent App Signing Certificate:     - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)

As soon as I build again, the issue goes away, and vice versa. Strangely, if I revert to the Legacy Build System (File>Project Settings...) the issue never appears.

It's also worth mentioning that there aren't issues with running the extensions when it does build.

Does anyone have the same issue or suggestions to work around it?